# How post message in a group using Yammer .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, yammer

How I post message in particular group using Yammer .NET SDK. I am using "Yammer.Oss.Api" currently.

I have written following code, but this method post message as public (All company)

```
  public async Task PostMessage(string Body, string Title, List listOfUsers)
        {
            var messageObject = new MessageObject()
            {
                Body = Body,
                Title = Title,
                Users = string.Join(",", listOfUsers.ToArray())
            };
            await _messageRepository.PostMessageAsync(messageObject);
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the code what you have tried?